# jquery not working on the site menu sharepoint 2013

Tags: jquery

okai I have been experiencing a really odd problem

I am using jquery to remove css from sharepoint site menu ,

when I log in as site owner it working well , but when I login as a site visitor the jquery doesn't  work , I have checked it with the firebug , the jquery code is executing its getting all the elements but the imapact is not showing on the page

first I thought it was because the masterpage mught have remained unpublished , so I made sure the master page was checked in and published I even remove the versioning for the master page library ,

Please help me out , is it related to security ?? I am just removing the css from the a tag inside the li , that sharepoint generates for a menu item 
 and yeah one more thing I am using fba .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the selectors you are using in your jQuery as it is possible that the page being rendered when viewed as a visitor has a different enough structure to interfere with them.

Comment: no I wrote I debugged it with firebug !!!!! , its getting all the objects in the selector , but its not reflecting in the display

Comment: just out of curiosity, does your code work if you use setTimeout() to execute it about 5 seconds after the page loads (for testing only) it may be that another IE-only event is blocking or resetting the changes made by your code.

Comment: Dave  you were right , I totally overlooked it may be I still need some more time to get comfortable with firebug's script debugging , SharePoint generates a different id for the div container of menu for different user groups

Comment: The IDs that SharePoint generates for Html elements are best considered as "carved in silly putty" as they are almost all subject to change.  A selector based on class or Html hierarchy generally works much better than one on ID - in SharePointville anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The menu is different based on the permissions of the user. So a Site Owner will see Site Settings but a read only user will not. It could very well be permission related depending on what your script is trying to do. Could you post it so we can try to help?